# RxAndroid - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Another strategy was already registered

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I am writing a unit test and need to mock an Observable (from retrofit)

The code in the tested component is as follows:

```
getApiRequestObservable()
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(...)
```

In the unit test (against the JVM so `AndroidSchedulers` are not available) I need to make it all synchronous so my tests will look like:

```
@Test
public void testSomething() {
    doReturn(mockedResponse).when(presenter).getApiRequestObservable();
    presenter.callApi();
    verify(object,times(1)).someMethod();
}
```

To do this, I should register hooks in a setUp() method:

```
@Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        // AndroidSchedulers.mainThread() is not available here so we fake it with this hook
        RxAndroidPlugins.getInstance().registerSchedulersHook(new RxAndroidSchedulersHook() {
            @Override
            public Scheduler getMainThreadScheduler() {
                return Schedulers.immediate();
            }
        });

       // We want synchronous operations
        RxJavaPlugins.getInstance().registerSchedulersHook(new RxJavaSchedulersHook(){
            @Override
            public Scheduler getIOScheduler() {
                return Schedulers.immediate();
            }
        });
    }
```

But this throws the above exception as I am apparently not allowed to register two hooks. Is there any way around that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you're not resetting test state - you can verify that by running single test. To fix your particular problem you need to `reset` rx plugins state like so:

```
@Before
public void setUp(){
    RxJavaPlugins.getInstance().reset();
    RxAndroidPlugins.getInstance().reset();
    //continue setup
    ...
}
```

You can even wrap the reset into a reusable `@Rule` as described by [Alexis Mas  blog post](http://alexismas.com/blog/2015/05/20/unit-testing-rxjava/):

```
public class RxJavaResetRule implements TestRule {

    @Override
    public Statement apply(Statement base, Description description) {
        return new Statement() {
            @Override
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                //before: plugins reset, execution and schedulers hook defined

                RxJavaPlugins.getInstance().reset();
                RxAndroidPlugins.getInstance().reset();
                // register custom schedulers
                ...
                base.evaluate();
            }
        };
    }
}
```